# RegisterType in autofac causing filename unknown exception in mono

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, autofac

I have been working on a MVC project in visual studio on Windows where everything works correctly. However, when I try to get the project working on Xamarin with the mono compiler for OSX, I'm having troubles with the autofac type registration.

In my project I do the following:

```
public void OnContainerConfiguration(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Connection>().As<IConnection>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<MongodbConfiguration>().As<IMongodbConfiguration>().SingleInstance();
}
```

Where I register my Connection class in Autofac using the interface it implements. When I do this with the mono compiler I get the following exception:

```
at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3[TLimit,TActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle]..ctor (Autofac.Core.Service defaultService, Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData activatorData, Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle style) [0x0004e] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.ForType[TImplementer] () [0x00023] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterType[TImplementer] (Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder) [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Project.Base.Database.ModuleConfiguration.OnContainerConfiguration (Autofac.ContainerBuilder containerBuilder) [0x00002] in /Users/sl053/Documents/Project/src/Project.Base.Database/ModuleConfiguration.cs:13 
at Project.Base.Container.Configuration.ApplicationContainer.Startup () [0x00022] in /Users/sl053/Documents/Project/src/Project.Base.Container/Configuration/ApplicationContainer.cs:29 
at Project.Web.UI.MvcApplication.Application_Start () [0x00001] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.4.0-c7sr1/bockbuild-mono-4.4.0-branch-c7sr1/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295
```

I have been already been looking for similar issues on stackoverflow and this is what I found that is exactly the same issue as I just described:
[Autofac Dependency Injection works in Debug but crashes in Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924391/autofac-dependency-injection-works-in-debug-but-crashes-in-release)

But a solution they advise me to ignore the System.Core in the linker. This linker is however only used by the android/ios compilers and it seems like its not used by mono.

Does anybody have any more info about this problem?

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting, both on Windows and on Mac OS X?

Comment: That is correct. I would like to be able to run the web application (that already is running correctly on windows) also on mac osx by using the mono compiler.