# Unity, "System.Action" is delegate and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, delegates, unity-container

Using Unity, I am currently receiving this error message.

> The current type, System.Action`1[smsmessage.SmsApiConfiguration], is delegate and cannot be constructed. Unity only supports resolving Func<T> and Func<IEnumerable<T>> by default.

Here is SMSService class code.

```cs
    public static Action<SmsApiConfiguration> DefaultConfigurator =>
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AccessTokenProvider = new DefaultSmsApiAccessTokenProvider();
                    var baseUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
                    if (baseUri != null)
                    {
                        if (!baseUri.EndsWith("/"))
                        {
                            baseUri = string.Concat(baseUri, "/");
                        }
                        baseUri = string.Concat(baseUri, "api/message/");
                        cfg.SmsApiBaseUri = new Uri(baseUri);
                    }
                };
             
    
            public SmsService() : this(DefaultConfigurator)
            {
            }
    
            public SmsService(Action<SmsApiConfiguration> config)
            {
                if (config == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
                }
                try
                {
                    _configuration = new SmsApiConfiguration();
                    config(_configuration);
                    ValidateSmsApiConfiguration(_configuration);
                }
                catch (UriFormatException uex)
                {
                    _logger.Exception(uex, "Invalid SMS API base uri");
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

And here code of SmsApiConfiguration class

```cs
public class SmsApiConfiguration
{
    public Uri SmsApiBaseUri { get; set; }
    public ISmsApiAccessTokenProvider AccessTokenProvider { get; set; }
}
```

Below I am trying to resolve SMSservice and SmsApiConfiguration  in Unity.COnfig

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<SmsApiConfiguration>();

container.RegisterType<ISmsService, SmsService>(
    new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Can anyone guide me how we can register Delegate in Unity?

Comment: You can but you have to define the action on your DI container I am not sure this has any benefit. `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Add>((a, b) => a + b);`. Source : https://christianfindlay.com/2020/05/15/c-delegates-with-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to register an Action into a DI Container (Autofac)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816616/is-there-any-way-to-register-an-action-into-a-di-container-autofac)

Comment: No this is not related to my question :( in my class we are passing Action<SmsApiConfiguration>. I just need to pass this one also from Unity Config class.

Comment: Your injection constructor contains an awful lot of code and calls its dependencies. [Read this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) to understand why you should try to prevent doing this.

Comment: The problem is the line `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);` - simply remove it. The `Action` delegate is already defined in the `System` namespace, so there is really no need to define it.